# I just completed my exam and i was confident about my answers however i got 2 wrong and i just want to know what was the correct answer

Tags: sql

Write the SQL code For each of the problem below in the space indicated (Answer).    Determine which of the two tables (Student or Grade) will be used for each problem.
Student(StudentID, StudentName, Course ,  Status, Gender, Address, DateAdmitted)
Grade(StudentID, SubjectCode, Grade, Comment, AcademicYear, Semester)
Course is char(5)
Status is char(15) with possible values of ‘Regular’ or ‘Irregular’
Address is varchar(50)
DateAdmitted is of Date data type
Comment can be ‘Passed’ or ‘Failed’
AcademicYear ic char(7) with format of AY99-99  e.g.  ‘AY20-21’
Semester is  char(1)  with possible values of  ‘1’, ‘2’, or ‘S’

2. Count how many students were admitted for the year 2019.
   My Answer:
   SELECT COUNT (StudentID)
   FROM Grade
   WHERE AcademicYear=’AY19-20’;
3. List the student records if the student address has a ‘Manila’ or  ‘Mla.’ in it.
   My Answer:
   SELECT *
   FROM Student
   WHERE Address=’Manila’ OR Address=’Mla’;

can somebody help me figure out what is the correct query for the questions

Comment: 3) I suppose you should have used LIKE, to get "has a Manila or Mla _in it_".

Comment: 2) Use year field of DateAdmitted value, in Student table.

Comment: For 2 you would be counting the number of grades - likely a student gets more than one grade

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st Answer was looking Right

but in Second You Should use Like Because Question in Address has ‘Manila’ or ‘Mla' in it
so your address contain those value for that use like query

`Select * from Student Where Address like '%Manila%' or Address Like '%Mla%'`

Comment: thank you, i re-read  the question and that was really on me not understanding it well enough